# Checking out a project on github with the Eclipse CVS client?

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, github, egit

I am playing with my eclipse cvs functionality (on my windows box), is there a way to check out a project hosted on github?

Anyone shows me a pointer? Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Not with the CVS client. You need to install [git for Windows](http://github.com/guides/using-git-and-github-for-the-windows-for-newbies) or a [git plugin for Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/).

CVS and git are two different source code version control systems. Other popular choices are Subversion or Mercurial. You have to use different clients or Eclipse plugins for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Use EGit, which provides Git support as part of Eclipse and is available in both the latest Helios builds as well as the upcoming Indigo release.